# OpenCV installation issue on mac mavericks

Tags: opencv, cmake, osx-mavericks, homebrew

So yesterday CleanMyMac destroyed some system files of mavericks, I repaired (reinstalled) mavericks and after that I got an error from Xcode that "assert.h" cannot be found. So I figured I install command line tools with "xcode-select --install" which I have no idea if it has solved my issue or not, and then I noticed all opencv libraries can not be found too. 
I uninstalled OpenCV with "brew unisntall opencv"
I have been trying to reinstall it ever since but I had No luck.
Running "brew install opencv" tells me :

```
==> make
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/algorithm.cpp.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/array.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Unfortunately I don't know what to do with this error,
I used cmake -j8 and I got:

```
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/transupp.c.o
Linking C static library ../lib/liblibjpeg.a
[  6%] Built target libjpeg
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried what was my last hope, "sudo port install opencv" and I get :
Computing dependencies for opencvError: Unable to execute port: can't read "configure.cxx_stdlib":     no such variable

I tried selfupdate for macports but it doesnt work either.
so now Im stuck does anybody have any idea? it would be much appreciated.

ps I have assigned my user as the owner of /usr/local just in case: "sudo  chown -R $User /usr/local"

Comment: Run `make` without `-j8`, please. Only this way do you see nicely where the error is coming from. Also, please fix your spelling, punctuation and capitalisation of words at the beginning of sentences.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up your question! +1 and welcome to SO.

Comment: Hello, I did what you asked me to do about capitalization and thank you for welcoming me to SO.
running "make" returns 'stdarg.h' file not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it, 
my Xcode was 5.1 and I was trying to avoid the upgrade, but as I ran out of options, I updated to Xcode 6 and after that "brew update" found few updates and then "brew install opencv" worked like it should have done in the first place.